# GIT: Two different repositories with one shared folder

Tags: android, ios, git, cordova, repository

I am currently creating a mobile app and I use Phonegap to deploy it to different platforms. We currently have created the app for the Android Platform and the iOS Platform. The Android one has a git repository, the iOS one does not (yet).
Both app versions have a www folder which are extremely similar (only the phonegap.js and plugin files differ). I wish to create a secondary GIT repository for iOS which shares the www folder from the original repository (Android), so I don't have to copy-paste the files every time.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could use put the shared folder in a separate repository and include it as a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) in both your Android and iOS repos.

Comment: Came in here to say that. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share files across git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1540879/), [Share code between rails projects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6004681/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules), you can also try [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree). You can also check [Sharing code between projects with git subtree](http://psionides.eu/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/)